# Regex to match a word followed by a variation of things

Tags: regex

I've been working on writing some regex in Postgres to filter out some of the junk in my strings.  Here are some of the various cases I encounter:

```
AUTO PARTS STORE 15
AUTO PARTS STORE #15
AUTO PARTS STORE #A15
AUTO PARTS STORE #AB15
AUTO PARTS STORE #A 15
AUTO PARTS STORE #A A15
AUTO PARTS STORE #15A
AUTO PARTS STORE #15-15
```

The digits after # could be one or more.  Also, there could be no space between "STORE" and "#".

What I am trying to filter is "STORE" and any store number after, no matter how it is formatted.

So far, this is what I have developed:

```
select regexp_replace(estab_name,E'STORE (#)?( )?([A-Z])?([A-Z])?( )?\\d+\\Z',' ')
```

Here is an example of some of the cases I'm missing, and what I would like to return (note - this was a third party edit based on comments - to show OP what I think he means; and inviting corrections):

```
If the input string is:              I would like to remove:    I would like to return:
7-ELEVEN FOOD STORE #11150A          STORE #11150A                7-ELEVEN FOOD
7-ELEVEN FOOD STORE #20132C          STORE #20132C                7-ELEVEN FOOD
7-ELEVEN FOOD STORE #2306-2134       STORE #2306-2134             7-ELEVEN FOOD
7-ELEVEN STORE #2301-14410N          STORE #2301-14410N           7-ELEVEN
7-ELEVEN STORE # 14279B TODD BAXTER  STORE # 14279B TODD BAXTER   7-ELEVEN
84 LUMBER COMPANY, LP, STORE: #0922  STORE: #0922                 84 LUMBER COMPANY, LP,
BIG LOTS STORE# 1886                 STORE# 1886                  BIG LOTS
KROGER STORE J-978                   STORE J-987                  KROGER
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm very new to writing complex regex and this is killing my brain right now.

Comment: Could you show what you expect the output to be? For example, for `7-ELEVEN STORE #2301-14410N`, do you want `STORE #2301`, `STORE 2301`, `STORE 2301-14410`, ...?

Comment: Sure not problem.  I am looking to remove any store and number information.  So, from the examples above:
7-ELEVEN FOOD STORE #11150A             7-ELEVEN FOOD  
7-ELEVEN FOOD STORE #20132C             7-ELEVEN FOOD  
7-ELEVEN FOOD STORE #2306-2134          7-ELEVEN FOOD  
7-ELEVEN STORE #2301-14410N             7-ELEVEN  
7-ELEVEN STORE # 14279B TODD BAXTER     7-ELEVEN   
84 LUMBER COMPANY, LP, STORE: #0922     84 LUMBER COMPANY, LP,  
BIG LOTS STORE# 1886                    BIG LOTS  
KROGER STORE J-978                      KROGER

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble with adding in line breaks.

Comment: If you edit your answer it will be easy to make the line breaks appear. I have edited your question with what I believe you are asking - please confirm that is correct. It might be that with "filter" you mean "keep", or "remove"...

Answer (score 3):

From the examples shown surely you're just after:

```
 STORE ?:? ?#?[A-Z0-9 -]+$
```

Comment: Technically, the dash should go at the front of the character set, otherwise it's supposed to be between two characters.

Comment: @Raceimaztion no so. A literal dash can be first or last

Comment: Really? I read the opposite a long time ago and have stuck to that ever since - is there a particular reason? As no errors ever seem to arise from having them at the end? I'm happy to change it though, if this is actually bad practice for whatever reasons

Comment: I've run into several regex implementations that give errors for trailing dashes.

Answer (score 0):

use \b for word boundries

```
 \bSTORE.*
```

Answer (score 0):

If my interpretation of what you are asking is correct, then what you are trying to match is "everything after the word 'STORE' until the end of the string". In which case your regex is simply

```
STORE.*$
```

You can see this in action at http://rubular.com/r/05sNzmXdqS .  If my interpretation is backwards, and you want to match "everything before the word `STORE`" then your regex is

```
^.*(?=STORE)
```

Using the "lookahead" to say "everything up to where the characters to your right are "STORE". You can see this at work at http://rubular.com/r/7Up8vVwzZa

If you need the space before "STORE" to be eliminated as well, I am sure you can figure out how to change the expression.